# How can I put an image gallery inside of a Bootstrap Modal?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried using the example from this contributor: http://www.bootply.com/alcaraz/QxGeDFsS8G

However, when I try to apply it to my scenario, the "image category" links just take me back to the top of my page when I click them. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center wrap_title">
            <h2>Photographer Photography</h2>


        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInDown text-center">
            <a title="New Life" href="#"><h3>NEWLIFE</h3>
            <img class="thumbnail img-responsive newb"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInDown text-center">
            <a title="Still Growing" href="#"><h3>STILL GROWING</h3>
            <div class="kid"></div></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInDown text-center">
            <a title="Family" href="#"><h3>FAMILY</h3>
            <div class="fam"></div></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row tworow">

            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-6  wow fadeInDown text-center">
            <a title="Seniors" href="#"><h3>SENIOR</h3>
            <div class="milestone"></div></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInDown text-center">
            <a title="YOU + ME" href="#"><h3>YOU + ME</h3>
            <div  class="unme"></div></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInDown text-center">
            <a title="I DO" href="#"><h3>I DO</h3>
            <div  class="marriage"></div></a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>



   <div class="hidden" id="img-repo">



                    <!--#image-1 -->
                        <div class="item" id="image-1">
                            <img  class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="1" src="img/galleries/baby/1.png" alt="">
                        </div>

                        <div class="item" id="image-1" >
                            <img  class="thumbnail img-responsive"  title="2" src="img/galleries/baby/2.png" alt="">
                        </div>

                        <div class="item" id="image-1">
                            <img  class="thumbnail img-responsive"  title="3" src="img/galleries/baby/3.png" alt="">
                        </div>

                        <div class="item" id="image-1">
                            <img  class="thumbnail img-responsive"  title="4" src="img/galleries/baby/4.png" alt="">
                        </div>

                        <div class="item" id="image-1">
                            <img  class="thumbnail img-responsive"  title="5" src="img/galleries/baby/5.png" alt="">
                        </div>

                        <div class="item" id="image-1">
                            <img  class="thumbnail img-responsive"  title="6" src="img/galleries/baby/6.png" alt="">
                        </div>

                        <div class="item" id="image-1">
                            <img  class="thumbnail img-responsive"  title="7" src="img/galleries/baby/7.png" alt="">
                        </div>

                        <div class="item" id="image-1">
                            <img  class="thumbnail img-responsive"  title="8" src="img/galleries/baby/8.png" alt="">
                        </div>

                        <div class="item" id="image-1">
                            <img  class="thumbnail img-responsive"  title="9" src="img/galleries/baby/9.png" alt="">
                        </div>

                        <div class="item" id="image-1">
                            <img  class="thumbnail img-responsive"  title="10" src="img/galleries/baby/10.png" alt="">
                        </div>

                        <div class="item" id="image-1">
                            <img  class="thumbnail img-responsive"  title="11" src="img/galleries/baby/11.png" alt="">
                        </div>

                        <div class="item" id="image-1">
                            <img  class="thumbnail img-responsive"  title="12" src="img/galleries/baby/12.png" alt="">
                        </div>

                </div>       
            </div>

            <!-- MODAL CODE -->
            <div class="modal" id="modal-gallery" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                         <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                            <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="modal-carousel" class="carousel">

                            <div class="carousel-inner">           
                            </div>

                            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#modal-carousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
                        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#modal-carousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>

                    </div>
                </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To me it looks like the href of the gallery categories should point to something else. In the example I gave though, they point to "#".  I cannot figure out why this works on the example but not in my situation. At the moment I have only created the HTML for the first category's images. Once I can get this to work I will add the additional category images. Is there something simple I am overlooking?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the javascript code added? And a quick look at the source, the <a> tag is mantadory. Just use CSS to add a pointer cursor.

Comment: I have the javascript code in a separate js file. It is listed in the js links at the bottom of the actual page. I only included the HTML that I am currently working on in the question. Sorry. Also, what do you mean the <a> tag is mandatory? Do you see it missing somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: Little typo, it is not mantadory. Any console errors?

Comment: There are a few but none are referencing this chunk of code or any of the js or css code that is being used here. Mostly "modernizer" and "PIE" errors.
If I remove the <a> tags how would the image categories be clickable?

Comment: Also, you need to wrap the JS from Bootply in jQuery $(document).ready(function(){ .. js code here.. }(); so that is binds properly after the DOM is loaded.. Otherwise the click handler won't work.

Comment: @Skelly , Are you talking about in the JS file or I need to have the JS code on the HTML file wrapped in jQuery? Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolved the issue.

wrap the JS from Bootply in jQuery `$(document).ready(function(){ .. js code here.. }();` so that is binds properly after the DOM is loaded.